Changing colour of the category tag on my posts
I am on the Basel theme on Wordpress and cannot find a way to change the colour of the attached tags on my posts or a way to just remove these tags completely in live while still using the categories in the back end. Anyone know how to do either?
I've tried going via theme settings but the "styles and colours" section is empty, and I am not too comfortable writing my own CSS yet.
